# Binning data and calculating MAE for each bin in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics, binning

I have two arrays:

```
Obs=([])
abs_error=([])
```

I want to use Obs to define the bins. For example, Where Obs is 1 to 2, bin abs_error into bin#1. Then where Obs is 2 to 3, bin abs_error into bin#2. etc.

Once I have my binned abs_error (which was binned by Obs) I want to calculate the mean of each bin and then plot the mean of each bin on the y-axis vs the bins on the x-axis.

How do I go about binning the abs_error by bins defined by the Obs? And how do I calculate the mean of each bin once this is done?

Right now I have:

```
abs_error=np.array([2.214033842086792 2.65031099319458 2.021354913711548 ... 2.831442356109619 1.9227538108825684 0.19358205795288086])
obs=np.array([3.3399999141693115 1.440000057220459 1.2799999713897705 ... 5.78000020980835 6.050000190734863 7.75])
bin_boundaries=np.array([0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0,13.0,14.0,15.0,16.0,17.0,18.0,19.0,20.0])

idx = np.digitize(obs, bin_boundaries)
mn_ = np.bincount(idx,abs_error) / np.bincount(idx)
print mn

[83.09254473  3.18577858  2.82887524  2.78532805  2.43264693  1.96835116 1.77645996  1.66138196  1.5972414   1.57512014  1.53094066  1.7965252 1.98050336  2.29916244  3.06640482  4.66769505  3.16787195]
```

I can't print the whole arrays because they are very big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your bins are all the same size you can use floor division to obtain bin indices from `Obs`, in your example.

```
idx = (Obs // 1).astype(int)
```

If not use `np.digitize` instead.

```
idx = np.digitize(Obs, bin_boundaries)
```

Once you have indices use them with `np.bincount` to obtain the means.

```
mn = np.bincount(idx, abs_error) / np.bincount(idx)
```

Comment: I think I must be doing something wrong. I am getting a weird number for the mean of the first bin. I have edited my question above to include the code with your updated answer. I am getting a mean of 83 for the first bin which can't be because the max value for obs is 17 and the max value for abs_error is 13. so I don't see how the means in any of the bins could exceed this. Can you tell what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. Turns out I had some nans in the array screwing up the results. I masked the arrays for where there are nans and this seemed to fix my issue. However, if I get nans on the upper part of my array does that mean there is no count in those bins? for example I get mn=[ nan 3.18577858 2.82887524 ......1.57512014 1.53094066 1.7965252
 1.98050336 2.29916244 3.06640482 4.66769505 3.16787195  nan
   nan  nan  nan  nan] and for bincount(idx)=[   0  157  458  677  855  920  979  .......
    4    2    2    0    0    0    0    0 3133]

Comment: @HM14 Yep, the mean of an empty bin is undefined, so `NaN` is the appropriate answer. Technically, what happens is a `0 / 0` where the first zero is the sum and the second zero is the element count.